# apache bench like for mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing, profiling, benchmarking, apachebench

Does it exist a tool like ab (apache bench) for mysql?

ex: I create a table, I fill as i want (some MO of rows)

then:

shell> tool -conccurency=20 -requests=2000 -query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = 42"

will result into some summarized result

I know that mysqlslap seems to play something like that, but it seems to work only with a mysqlslap database (a fake one). I couldn't make it work with an existing DB

Comment: Note that identical queries executed within a short time frame will probably get cached by MySQL. You would have to randomize it or create a much larger set of test queries to get an idea of general performance. Although if you (like with Apache Bench) only care about number of concurrent connections and requests/s, it should be fint. Just a thought :)

Comment: No since I use a "SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF; SELECT * ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I have to write my requests like this:

SELECT my_db.my_table ....  for mysqlslap use my own db